# Can I block an insert inside a trigger on Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert, oracle11g

So, what I want to do is to block an insert if the condition is met. In this case, I'm developing a simple library database system and I don't want to allow someone to be able to borrow a book if that certain person has already borrowed 2 books and still hasn't returned any of them.

I need to do this via trigger, is it possible? Also, I'd like to know if I can supply a query into the WHEN clause like I did.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_borrowing_limit
BEFORE INSERT ON Borrowing
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NROW
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Borrowing WHERE RETURN_DATE IS NULL AND NROW.ID = Borrowing.ID > 2
BEGIN
?
END
```

Comment: `raise_application_error(-20101, 'You already borrowed 2 books');`

Comment: Look at example 10-5 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't supply a query for the `WHEN` clause. From the [Oracle 11 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS1984) (search for "WHEN (condition)" once you get to the page):

> Restrictions on WHEN (condition)
>
> - If you specify this clause, then you must also specify FOR EACH ROW.
> - The condition cannot include a subquery or a PL/SQL expression (for example, an invocation of a user-defined function).

As for preventing the row insert, the comment from Mihai is the way to go. Your front end can catch the exception, and if it's error number `-20101` (per Mihai's example) you'll know that the person already has two books out. Note that some drivers will report the absolute value of the exception number, so the error number that reaches you may be `20101`.

---

**Addendum:** a followup question asked how to apply the "two books out" logic since it's not valid for the `WHEN` clause.

The answer is to drop the `WHEN` clause and put the logic into the trigger body. Note that I normally stick with the standard `NEW` for referencing the new row, so my answer doesn't have the `REFERENCING NEW AS NROW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_borrowing_limit
  BEFORE INSERT ON Borrowing
DECLARE
  booksOut NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO booksOut
    FROM Borrowing
    WHERE RETURN_DATE IS NULL AND NEW.ID = Borrowing.ID;
  IF booksOut > 2 THEN
    -- Next line courtesy of Mihai's comment under the question
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'You already borrowed 2 books');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I do need to apply this error only when the number of books someone has borrowed and not returned is more than 2. I suppose there's no way to calculate that number without using COUNT, right? What can I do?

Comment: @Henrique In your case probably the simplest way to enforce cross-row constraint would be encapsulating the logic into a PL/SQL procedure(where you do counting, checking, exception raising and insertion into the `borrowing` table if everything's OK). The attempt to enforce a constraint that is crossing rows using a trigger **may** result in  `mutating table` error. **may** because when you use `before insert` row level trigger, as you do, you can get away with a simple `insert.. into.. values()` statement, but you definitely hit the `mutating table` error with `insert..into..select` statement.

Comment: Henrique - I agree with the @NicholasKrasnov comment that you may want to encapsulate this logic. Triggers can be tricky because of the mutating table rule. Still, if you want to try a trigger in this instance I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked dropping the WHEN clause. The only weird thing now is that it's returning Error at line 4: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."ID": invalid identifier and now I can't compare the new ID with the already existing IDs (it's even showing the error on the wrong line (the one I declared the number variable)) EDIT: I also dropped the REFERENCING NEW AS NROW sentence.